# Opencart - The register user page just reloads when we click continue

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I am facing an issue with my open cart website wherein the user registration page when I hit the continue button by not entering some required fields the page just reloads without showing the validation message.

The user registration is working fine, the problem happening is when I don't enter any required field like first name or email or forget to check the agreement terms, the page just refreshes without showing the required field validation message or any error when the continue is clicked.

Link: https://www.pickupbest.com/index.php?route=account/register

Varun

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see the validation message after reload - open page code view (Ctrl+U in Chrome and Firefox). There you will find your error messages:

```
<div class="text-danger">First Name must be between 1 and 32 characters!</div>
```

[image]

I can see them for a split second in the browser, but then some JS removing it. It may be in the current template.

in **register.tpl** look for

```
$(element).parent().find('.text-danger').remove();
```

Try to comment it and see whats happens.

Or it could be **catalog/view/javascript/productenquiry/productenquiry.js**, this line

```
$('.alert, .text-danger').remove();
```

Try to comment it, clear cache of your browser (Ctrl+F5, reload page with cache cleaning).

Comment: Thanks for your help focus.style. the productenquiry.js file was the culprit. Commenting the line in that file solved the problem. Now I have to figure the drawbacks of commenting that line.

Comment: I think, there is a way in your template to make registration wort using ajax. Anyway, if an answer was helpful - you could mark it as a correct.

Comment: Maybe, catalog/view/javascript/productenquiry/productenquiry.js should be added only on product page.